# Is it possible to view all issues you have against a project in GitHub from within PhpStorm?

Tags: github, phpstorm

We use GitLab, Tower and YouTrack with PhpStorm. We are thinking about moving to GitHub and using its issue logging/tracking feature instead of YouTrack (as much to see if we prefer it at the moment as anything else).

We have been trying to work out if there is a way to show all the issues logged in GitHub in PhpStorm but don't seem to be able to. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how? We assume it would be via a plugin but can't find one that does it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind me asking what does not work exactly? Were you able to configure GitHub/GitLab task server integration, does the test connection work? 

Also, please check this one:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259427

Comment: That seems to be handling tasks, allowing me to hump into or create branches. I'm referring to the issues that you can log against a repository, eg the tasks that need to be done for example. Thanks though.